# Proving the limit is a fixed point

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Let $f: [a,b] \to[a,b]$ such that: $$ \lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert \le K\lvert x-y\rvert$$
when $0<K<1$.
I already managed to prove there is exactly one fixed point.

Now I need to prove that the series defined: $a_{n+1}=f(a_n) , a_0 = x$ for $x \in [a,b]$ converges to this fixed point. I know that given it does converge, then the fixed point is the limit. Any help is proving it actually converges? 
Thanks!

Comment: Hint : Is it a Cauchy sequence ? Notice also that $\sum_{n \geq 0} K^n$ converges.

Comment: Do you mean the sequence (not the series) $(a_n)_n,$ or the series $\sum_n a_n$? (I assume the former)

Comment: How did you prove that there is a fixed point without looking at a sequence of such sort?

Comment: This is, of course, a very special case of Banach Fixed Point Principle: if the metric space $(X,d)$ is complete and $f:X\to X$ fulfills for some $K\in(0,1)$ the condition $d\bigl(f(x),f(y)\bigr)\le Kd(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in X$, then $f$ admits the unique fixed point. The proof goes exactly in the same way as in the case of a closed interval.

Comment: Intermediate value theorem

Comment: @user401516: of course, this argument gives us the existence of a fixed point, not the uniqueness. This is gueranteed by the limit construction, which is not always possible. It is, whenever $f$ is contractive, as discussed here.

Comment: @szw1710 no need for a sequence. Assume two distinct fixed points, apply the function to both, and then use that $K <1$ to conclude that this is impossible.

Comment: @Clement C. - yes, of course :) Thanks for this valuable remark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Idea:** show it is Cauchy. For this, you can use that for any $n,m\geq 0$
$$\rvert a_{n+m}-a_n\rvert \leq K \lvert a_{n+m-1}-a_{n-1} \rvert
\leq \dots \leq K^n \lvert a_{m}-a_{0} \rvert \leq K^n \lvert b-a \rvert.
$$
Now, $K\in(0,1)$...

Comment: great! but I still dont know how to end it, I mean we got to a point where $K^n\lvert b-a\rvert$ converges, but how do we show that its smaller than any $\epsilon$ ?

Comment: Because $K^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$, there exists $N\geq 0$ such that $0\leq K^n \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{\lvert b-a\rvert }$ for all $n\geq N$.